# AP Management Vlan

Tags: vlan, access-point

I was wondering if it is possible to have guest WiFi network on subnet 192.168.1.0/24 and Access Points to that WiFi on subnet 10.0.0.0/24. What I am trying to do is to block WiFi users access to AP configuration sites.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

> I was wondering if it is possible to have guest WiFi network on subnet 192.168.1.0/24 and Access Points to that WiFi on subnet 10.0.0.0/24?

Since you asked a general question, yes it is possible. As a matter of fact, I highly recommend this approach and all wireless deployments I have a hand in do this if at all possible.

However, it is the "if at all possible" part where we an issue giving a specific answer based on your question as it directly relates to the equipment you have available.

I personally don't know of a single device (small business or better) sold as an "access point" that does not have this capability. Beyond that, the question is whether your switches/routers also have this capability. Without knowing more details, no one could give a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

very depend on the AP  , for example in Cisco AP you configure the port connecting the AP as a trunk and the MGM Vlan (10.0.0.0/24) will be configured as a Native Vlan on this port and just allow the data Vlan (192.168.1.0/24).

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure AP's to work in managment vlan and on switch set 2 Vlan's on AP's port: tagged managment vlan, and 1 (lan) vlan untagged for users.